# Structured Bindings : loop over deque of tuple

Tags: c++, c++17

I just installed the last version of Visual Studio and I have this deque of tuple :

```
using InstancesOfOneObject = std::tuple<DrawCmd, std::deque<bool>, std::deque<glm::mat4>>;
std::deque<InstancesOfOneObject> mInstancesByObject;
```

After, I want to traverse this deque with a for ranged loop :

```
for (const auto &[cmd, validites, matrices] : mInstancesByObject)
```

However, that does not work, but :

```
for (const auto &instance : mInstancesByObject) {
    const auto &[cmd, validities, matrices] = instance;
```

works well.

Is it normal? Is there a way to use something close to the first idea?

Comment: Yes but why for a std::map does it work... It should be the same problem, no?

Comment: Try this `for (auto&& [first,second] : mymap) {
    // use first and second
}` from the [range-for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) documentation

Comment: Okay that seems to work. But it is weird to use a rvalue reference here. I am going to look more in details the documentation, thanks ;)

Comment: Write it as an answer, I will accept it ;)

Comment: What compiler are you using?  A modified example works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/085ebf1f37b8cb8c)

Comment: I am using MSVC. But Bl4ckb0ne answered my question. The use of && allows forwarding and it solves my issue ;)

Comment: Ah, most likely a MSVS bug then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only difference between:

```
for (const auto &[cmd, validites, matrices] : mInstancesByObject) { ... }
```

and:

```
for (const auto &instance : mInstancesByObject) {
    const auto &[cmd, validities, matrices] = instance;
    ...
}
```

is that the latter allows you to still access `instance` whereas in the former it's an unnamed object. They are otherwise equivalent. If the former doesn't compile, you should file a bug with that compiler.